# Approval Process - choose the approver manually

Tags: approval-process

My question is can we allow user chose next step approver not from all users but just from some "group" of users - I don't think about actual group but about some people who should be able to approve?

(and yes - I know I can assign it to real group or assign to approver(s)).
But direct client wish is to chose 1 or more people depend on record.

For example having group or list of 40 users able to approve is confusing to the user, so he/she want to chose 1-4 of them who should be able to approve this particular record

Comment: I know it is has been a long time since you asked this question. But can't this be implemented using queues and approval processes. Basically, you could create different queues (groups what you call) and then create approval process with entry criteria to send to corresponding queue. If you have found a solution to your answer by now, it would be gr8 if you could post it so that we learn from it.